# Custom Validation in AJAX popup in mVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need to perform `custom validation` in `AJAX` `popup` in `MVC`. I have created a `CustomValidator` and am overriding the `IsValid()` method. Problem lies that the popup doesn't render the custom validations properly.

My code:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" />
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.ajax.unobtrusive/3.2.4/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#modalDialog").dialog({
                autoOpen:false,
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                modal: true
            });
            $("#opener").click(function () {
                $("#modalDialog").dialog("open");
            });
        });

        function OnSuccess(response)
        {
            $("#modalDialog").text(response);
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model MvcPopup.Controllers.HomeController.SomeModel
@{ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";}
<p>This is page content !!!</p>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="modalDialog" title="Basic Modal Dialog">
    <p>This is a basic modal dialog</p>
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "ID", OnSuccess = "OnSuccess" }))
   {
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Info</legend>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
   }
</div>
```

HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public class SomeModel
        {
            [CustomValidator]
            [Display(Name = "Email address")]
            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new SomeModel();
            return View();
        }   
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(SomeModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return PartialView();
            }
            return PartialView();
        }
```

CustomValidator.cs:

```
public class CustomValidator : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                if (value.ToString().Contains("X"))
                {
                    return ValidationResult.Success; ;
                }
                else
                {
                    return new ValidationResult("Enter an email address with letter X");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " is mandatory.Please enter it.");
            }
        }
    }
```

I can see that the `Custom Validations` are fired, but the render on the popup page is little bit crooked. Appears like below:

[image: On Load]

Now, I don't enter any value in the Email `textbox`, and click on `Submit`, I can see my custom validation "`Email Address is mandatory. Please enter it.`" gets fired and is evident on the popup page as below:

[image: Afterwards]

I mean, its pretty evident that the custom validation should appear near to the email `textbox` and things should look like a `popup`. Please help.

**EDIT**

`Validations` appear in the `popup` page, but the content is somewhat crooked. `I mean the content of the parent page too appear on the popup page`. Snapshot below. How to get rid of it? Please help.

[image]

Comment: `$("#modalDialog").html(response);` (not `,text()`)

Comment: Why not just use a `RegularExpressionAttribute` to ensure an `"X"` is included - there is no real point in this attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke: This X inclusion is just for demonstration purpose. I can have other valid kinds of custom validation.

Comment: I suggest you then read [THE COMPLETE GUIDE TO VALIDATION IN ASP.NET MVC 3 - PART 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Please see EDIT. Thanks.

Comment: Because that's what your partial view returns :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: How to get rid of it?

Comment: Create a separate partial view for the content you want to update (and get rid of the `OnSuccess(response)` function and use the `UpdateTargetId` option)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115304/discussion-between-anurag-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical and seen quite some time often. The reason that validation didn't fire is because the content like modal dialog is dynamic which is added/appeared on page later. The form validation has to parse the form again to validate the controls that are added dynamically to the page.

You have setup `OnSuccess()` so you can use it to parse the form.

```
function OnSuccess() 
{
    if($.validator)
    {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    }

    $("#modalDialog").html(response);
}
```

[**Visit here**](http://www.mfranc.com/javascript/unobtrusive-validation-in-partial-views/) for more info.

> Note that, this solution assumes that your validation is working fine.

Comment: The validation attribute does not implement `IClientValidatable` so reparsing is not necessary (just pointless extra overhead)

Comment: I think it is a good approach to implement `IClientValidatable` so to exploit the powers of jQuery validation library.

Comment: It will display the error message when the view is returned (as added to `ModelState`) - OP' issue is using `.text()` instead of `.html()`

Comment: @Rohit416: Please see EDIT. Thanks